# MySQL join / select on a table with transposed columns

Tags: mysql, join

If I have two tables such that the first, `tbl_names` is:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | Name1     |
+----+-----------+
| 2  | Name2     |
+----+-----------+
| 3  | Name3     |
+----+-----------+
```

and the second, `tbl_material` is:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| id | field1 | field2 | field3 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |      2 |      3 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  2 |      3 |      2 |      1 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

Where `field1`, `field2`, and `field3` are all foreign key columns referencing `tbl_names`. How could I fabricate a join / select statement in MySQL to produce the following output table:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| id | field1 | field2 | field3 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |  Name1 |  Name2 |  Name3 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  2 |  Name3 |  Name2 |  Name1 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

I could do something like the following:

```
SELECT m.id as id, n.name as field1
FROM   tbl_names n JOIN tbl_material m
ON     m.field1 = n.id
```

And get the output a column at a time, but if I were try try to do more than that, I feel like I'd end up with something where I'd see:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| id | field1 | field2 | field3 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |  Name1 |      2 |      3 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |  Name2 |      3 |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
...
```

Do I need to use something like a `group by` here to reduce the output get the correct number of output rows?

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor schema design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `JOIN` to the `tbl_names` table 3 times, once each to get the name for each `field`:

```
SELECT m.id, 
       n1.name AS field1,
       n2.name AS field2,
       n3.name AS field3
FROM tbl_material m
JOIN tbl_names n1 ON n1.id = m.field1
JOIN tbl_names n2 ON n2.id = m.field2
JOIN tbl_names n3 ON n3.id = m.field3
ORDER BY m.id
```

Output:

```
id  field1  field2  field3
1   Name1   Name2   Name3
2   Name3   Name2   Name1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hzikALxVQ3kvQt7mv9Z2cM/1)